# How organize chunked file transfer in both client and server side without developing own protocol?

Tags: java, c#, php, file-upload, httpurlconnection

I'm developing Java-applet down/uploading) large files from server. Server app can be written in any language, but now I'm interested in most popular ones - Java, C# and PHP.

Server applications will use my applet and must provide download/upload API for it. My goal is to specify requirements. As my files can be very large I want to transfer them in chunks. **I invented "bicycle" - own protocol for chunking and now I'm wondering is there built-in in language/web-server tools for replacing my bicycle?**

For clearence, short description of my bicycle -

1. Applet calls API method `initDownload(fileName,chunkSize)` and server sets up this property somewhere and returns to applet total number of chunks.
2. Applet calls API method `getFilePart(fileName,chunkNumber)` for each chunk. In the case of fail it may retry to get this chunk. Server's implementation is simply RandomAccessFile with seeking position to desired and returning appropriate bytes.
3. Applet calls API method `setFilePart(fileName,chunkNumber)` for each chunk.
4. Applet works via HTTPURLConnection.

I read about HTTPURLConnection's `setRequestHeader("Transfer-Encoding","chunked");`
and `setChunkedStreamingMode(chunkSize)` but didn't understand **how configure consumer side to accept chunking mode? Where chunk size is setted up? Or chunk size is not necessary due to protocol?** I mean, with chunking mode server can't simply open InputStream and read, AFAIK, he should turn on HTTP/1.1 or call some setter in RequestMapping-side, am I right?

**So, is my hypotesis below correct? Hypothesis:**

Upload to server - Applet side can simply include chunking with 2 rows of code - header for turning on chunking mode and setter for specifying chunk size. Server side can be simple open-InputStream-read-all code with simple configuration to HTTP/1.1. Is any web-server provides such configuration? I'm interested in famous servers like XAMPP for PHP; IIS for C#; Glassfish, Tomcat, JBOSS for JAVA and others which I don't know or forgot to mention.

Download to applet side - now, server should somehow turn on chunking in  response. Does PHP, C#  have methods like `setChunkedStreamingMode`? How turn on chunking in Java-HTTPURLConnection for receiving chunks? As I understand, `setChunkedStreamingMode` works only for sending data or this is incorrect?

In other words, I want just to open InputStream/OutputStream and rely on TCP like I rely on it for making "handshakes" -  is it possible?